# WebFlux execute request in background?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I have method that should return result or error message after executing `confirm` method and then do some background job. I wrote something similar to above but I'm not sure about method that invoked in `then`. Am i wrong? If yes, How can i run method in background using webflux?

```
    public Mono<Void> someMethod(...){
      return someReactiveApiClient.confirm().onErrorMap(...).then(doSomeBackgroundJob);
    }
```

Comment: so do you want to return instantly after `confirm` and execute `doSomeBackgroundJob` like fire and forget, or you want to return the 'result' of the `doSomeBackgroundJob`?
also, if not confirmed or on error, do you want to discard the job run?

Comment: I want to return result of confirm operation and if it was successful then execute background job and forget.

Comment: As I understand: change `.then` to `.doOnComplete`, this will run the job after the original publisher succesfully completed. Just before  `.doOnComplete`, use `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` to execute it  in different thread (choose the Scheduler best fit to your requierements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @zlaval mentioned, `publishOn()` can be used to switch execution contexts. The `publishOn` operator influences the threading context where the rest of the operators in the chain below it run, up to a new occurrence of `publishOn`. So the placement of `publishOn` is significant.

You can write your own scheduler or use one of the existing schedulers from [this class](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html) . You can read more about it [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers).

Thus, if you have some code like this (I am using elastic scheduler):

```
    Mono.just("Hello").log()
        .onErrorMap(err -> new RuntimeException("my exception"))
        .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
        .then(Mono.just("World").log())
        .subscribe();
```

you will see only this printed in console:

```
18:30:11.337 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
18:30:11.340 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | request(unbounded)
18:30:11.340 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onNext(Hello)
18:30:11.344 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.1 - | onComplete()
18:30:11.344 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onSubscribe([Synchronous Fuseable] Operators.ScalarSubscription)
18:30:11.344 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | request(unbounded)
18:30:11.344 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onNext(World)
18:30:11.344 [elastic-2] INFO reactor.Mono.Just.2 - | onComplete()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Thus **the second mono having `World` is being executed in another thread called `elastic-2` and not in the `main` thread**.

Note that, if your `confirm` method throws an error, then the background task wont occur. The execution will stop there.

eg. If you have something like this:

```
    Mono.error(new ArithmeticException()).log()
        .onErrorMap(err -> new RuntimeException("my exception"))
        .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
        .then(Mono.just("World").log())
        .subscribe();
```

then running this, will give output,

```
18:33:50.544 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.Error.1 - onSubscribe([Fuseable] Operators.EmptySubscription)
18:33:50.546 [main] INFO reactor.Mono.Error.1 - request(unbounded)
18:33:50.547 [main] ERROR reactor.Mono.Error.1 - onError(java.lang.ArithmeticException)
18:33:50.549 [main] ERROR reactor.Mono.Error.1 - 
java.lang.ArithmeticException: null
    at com.example.schooltimetable.Application.main(Application.java:29)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

You need similarly like this if your background job involves some I/O or network call.

```
    public Mono<Void> someMethod(...){
      return someReactiveApiClient.confirm()
               .onErrorMap(err -> {
                   //Your error handling logic. Remember to return an error
                   })
               .publishOn(Schedulers.elastic())
               .then(doSomeBackgroundJob);
    }
```

Comment: elastic is deprecated now, `.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return with the result of the `confirm()`, and after the original publisher is succesfully completed, it will call the job. `publishOn` indicates that the job have to run on different thread. You may have to choose the proper `Schedulers`, best fits to your requierements

```
public Mono<YourRequieredType> someMethod(...){
  return someReactiveApiClient.confirm().onErrorMap(...)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
        .doOnComplete(doSomeBackgroundJob);
}
```